# Laravel - Auto detecting Controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

Pretty new to Laravel and I'm slightly confused to how routing works.

In FuelPHP I'm used to using file structure to define routes.

E.g. I have admin/clients/add and I would use a class of Admin_Clients (and a method action_add) for this and so on.

Using Controller::detect() registers the class admin.clients but when it comes to resolve it, it choses the Admin_Controller class unless I define every single route which I want to avoid.

If anyone could help me out it would be much appreciated.

Laravel vs 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to have a naming convention in Laravel, especially for controllers.

In your case, renaming the `Admin_Clients` to `AdminClients_Controller` would probably be better idea.

Then, I would restrain from using `Controller::detect()`, and explicitly create Route to each controller as following:

```php
Route::controller('AdminClients');
```

From now, accessing of the `AdminClients_Controller` methods would work as following:

```
http://localhost/controller/method/arguments
```

For further explanation of how Routes work in Laravel, please refer to:

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#the-basics

Comment: Also useful to note that `Route::controller()` takes an array of controllers. E.g., `Route::controller(['home', 'admin', 'admin.users']);`